# IE8 Javascript profiler not showing source code

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

When using IE8's javascript profiler in the Developer Tools, why does it not show the url or line number in the report? If I double click on a function it says "Source code is not available for this location".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to go to the Script tab and click Start Debugging to get line numbers and file names in profiler results.

Instructions with pictures:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The debugger probably can't see the source of built-in JS functions, if that's what you mean